# Read json data into global variable in Node.js

Tags: file, node.js, readfile

I'm trying to read a json structure into a global variable, but cannot seem to get it to work.  I am using a callback for processing once it's read from the file (that part is working).

I'd like to have "source_files" populated.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var source_files = [];

function readConfig(callback) { 
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf-8', function (err, content) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(content);
    });             
}                       

readConfig(function(config) { 
    var settings = JSON.parse(config);
    var inputs = settings.inputs;

    for (var id=0; id < inputs.length; id++) {
        source_files.push(inputs[id].replace('./',''));
    }           
});

console.log(source_files);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that [`readFile` is *asynchronous*](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback). Your last line, `console.log(source_files)`, will run **before** the `readFile` callback has been called, and thus before the `readConfig` callback is called. You need to move that *into* the `readConfig` callback.

With your code as-is, here's what happens:

1. It creates the blank array.
2. It calls `readConfig`.
3. `readConfig` calls `readFile`.
4. `readFile` *starts* the asynchronous read operation and returns.
5. `readConfig` returns.
6. You log `source_files`, which is empty.
7. Later, the `readFile` operation finishes and the callback is called. It calls the `readConfig` callback.
8. The `readConfig` callback populates `source_files`, but it's a bit like a tree falling in the forest at that point, as nothing observes that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, `readFile` is asynchronous. If this is just start-up initialising code (i.e. doesn't matter if it blocks) you could use `readFileSync` instead (which throws `err` or returns `content`).

However, if `readConfig` can also be called in response to later input (e.g. a POSIX signal or a TCP request) then you must keep it asynchronous or risk blocking other I/O.